# Solution check - differential geometry, inducted metrics

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, differential-geometry, tensor-products, tensors

We are given the surface $T^2$ generated by the following parametrization: 
 $r(\theta^1, \theta^2) = (\gamma_1(\theta^1)\cos\theta^2, \gamma_1(\theta^1)\sin\theta^2, \gamma_3(\theta^1)) = (x^1, x^2, x^3)$ Where $\gamma(\theta) = (2+ \cos \theta, 0, \sin \theta)$ 
$r: (-\pi, \pi) \to \mathbb{R}^3$. 
The problem is to calculate the metric tensor $g_{ij}d\theta^i d\theta^j$ induced by the inclusion of $T^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the standard metric tensor $\delta_{ij}dx^idx^j$. 
I want to make sure I understand what is being asked, and that I do everything correctly. 
In $\mathbb{R^3}$, we have the Euclidean metric $\langle,\rangle$. 
Now, we want to find the induced metric by the immersion $i: T^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$, $i(x)=x$. 
By definition, the metric will simply be $g(p) = D_i(p)^{*}g_{\text{Euc}}(i(p))=g_{\text{Euc}}(p)$ [here $^*$ denotes pullback, $D$ is the differential, $g_{\text{Euc}}$ is the Euclidean metric]. 
So we really just need to compute the euclidean metric in coordinates $\theta^1, \theta^2$. 
To do that, we simply note that $g_{ij} = \left\langle\frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \theta^j} , \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \theta^i}\right\rangle$, and the rest is computation. 
 
Is everything correct? I am not sure about the use of the euclidean metric, as I didn't really understand what was the meaning behind "with the standard metric tensor". Even if it is the meaning, I would still like to know if what I did was accurate.

Comment: Tip: To denote an inner product use `\langle` and `\rangle`.

Comment: Anyone canv help?

Comment: what are the $\gamma_1,\gamma_3$?

Comment: @janmarqs the first and third coordinates of $\gamma$